# generating swf files

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, tomcat, flash

I have a flex webservice project 'simpleWebApp' running on the tomcat server. The simpleWebApp.swf file generated is in the webapp root folder of tomcat and it executes perfectly when i double click on the simpleWebApp.swf file

now i need the generated simpleWebApp.swf file to run when placed anywhere, any location.
 what i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the .swf and .html file to a folder(say testApp) inside your server's deploy folder.Then access your application http://localhost:8080/testApp/.swf.This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have correct path to the server where you webservice will be located, it's better to have this as a variable and path it in the flash vars to your swf. Also you may need [crossdomain.xml](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html), to be able to access you server from flash in a case if *anywhere != yourserver*

Answer (score 0):

Another way what i did is, in the flash builder i went to project/Export Release Build which Builds and export an optimized release-quality SWF file. now when i place  release build folder anywhere, my swf file works.